# What happens when you background the "success" screen of an inapp purchase?

Tags: android

So lets say I have IAB all set up and nice.

Then, I make a purchase for an item. Neat.

The "payment successful" shows on the Google UI.

And then, I background my app.

Will I receive an "OK" activity result? Will I receive an activity result from the service at all? Or will my purchase move on though happily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so this is strange and should actually be noted for people working with IAP:

If you see the screen that says "PAYMENT SUCCESSFUL" but then background the app, when you open the app again you will get a 0 (CANCELLED) activity result.

So, be sure to handle this in your app to prevent the loss of transactions.